# Table not aggregating properly

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to create a list of percentages from a dataset of transactional data using SAS/SQL to understand how a specific department contributes to overall sales count for a given quarter. For example, if there were 100 sales of Store ID 234980 and 20 of those were in department a in Q4 of 2006, then the list should output:

```
Store ID 234980 , 20%.
```

This is the code I am using to achieve this result.

```
data testdata;
    set work.dataset;
    format PostingDate yyq.;
run;

PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE aggregatedata AS
        SELECT DISTINCT testdata.ID,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN testdata.Store='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0
                        END)/COUNT(Store) as PERCENT,
             PostingDate
        FROM work.testdata
        group by testdata.ID, testdata.PostingDate;
QUIT;
```

However, the output I am receiving is more like this:

```
StoreID DepartmentA Quarter
    100           1  2014Q1
    100           0  2014Q2
    100           1  2014Q2
    100           0  2014Q2
    100           0  2014Q2
    100           0  2014Q2
    101           1  2015Q3
    101           0  2015Q3
    101           0  2015Q4
```

Why does my code not aggregate to the store level?

Comment: because you are including the date field -- you want to convert that to a quarter before you aggregate.

Comment: @Hogan The data step converts the format appropriately.

Comment: The data step converts the output -- that has no effect on the internal group by which happens on the server.  Try taking that field out and see if the results change.

Comment: PROC SQL doesn't recognize formatted values, like PROC FREQ or MEANs would. My suggestion would be to use a standard summary procedure instead.

Comment: And the output shown doesn't match the code you have posted. I get that you need to suppress things but it makes it hard to provide valid answers and becomes a guessing game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group by QTR then you need to transform your date values into quarter values. Otherwise '01JAN2017'd and '01FEB2017'd would be seen as two distinct values even though they would both display the same using the YYQ. format.

```
proc sql;
create table aggregatedata as
  select id
       , intnx('qtr',postingdate,0,'b') as postingdate format=yyq.
       , sum(store='A')/count(store) as percent
  from work.testdata
  group by 1,2
;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to set both DISTINCT and GROUP BY

Perhaps try:

```
 select t.testingdate
       ,t.StoreID
       ,t.Department
       ,count(t.*) / count(select t2.*
                           from testdata t2
                           where t.testingdate = t2.testingdate
                           and t.StoreID = t2.StoreID) AS Percentage
 from testdata t
 group by t.testingdate
         ,t.StoreID
         ,t.Department
```

Alternately you could use a left join, which may be more efficient.  The nested select to count all records, regardless of department may be more clear to read.